# Trying find state for services in Win32_Service

Tags: wmi

I am using wbemtest.exe to execute WQL queries. My goal is to obtain the state of services in Win32_Service class. My query is `select State from Win32_Service where DisplayName="Windows Defender"`. The result I am expecting is `Win32_Service.State=Stopped/Running`, but it is showing `Win32_Service=<no key>`. If I do `select * from Win32_Service where DisplayName="WIndows Defender"`, I obtain the only `Win32_Service.Name=WinDefend`". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just use "select * from win32_service" to get the list of all the services, then double click on the windows defender service to view its properties. win32_service.name and win32_service.displayname have different values. Is this confusing you?

Comment: no, that is not confusing me. My main objective is to use Java WMI libraries to obtain the running state of my applications.